# Is it possible for PowerShell to write message to multiple target

Tags: powershell, output, pipeline

Is there a usage of pipeline for PowerShell to Write-Output & write to file in the same time, without using a custom wrapping function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [`Tee-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177014.aspx). From help:

> The Tee-Object cmdlet sends the output of a command in two directions
>   (like the letter "T"). It stores the output in a file or variable and
>   also sends it down the pipeline. If Tee-Object is the last command in
>   the pipeline, the command output is displayed in the console.

Comment: Yes, it seems we can use .\Test.ps1 | Tee-Object -FilePath test.log